# Substitute the forward declared struct with lately defined struct

Tags: c++, namespaces, typedef, forward-declaration

I'm trying to substitute the forward *declared* struct B with lately *defined* struct A. Here is a code sample:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace n1 {
struct B;

namespace n3 {
    void func(B& b) {
        cout << "b\n";
    }
}

}

namespace n2 {
struct A{};
}

namespace n1 {
using B = n2::A;
}

int main() {
    n1::B b;
    n1::n3::func(b);
    return 0;
}
```

and got the following error:

```
conflicting declaration ‘using B = struct n2::A’
 using B = n2::A;
                ^
prog.cpp:5:8: note: previous declaration as ‘struct n1::B’
 struct B;
```

Is this trick possible somehow if it's even legal? Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the use-case? What is the original problem you try to solve by something like this (which isn't valid by the way)?

Comment: I have a function which accepts struct B. An *implementation* is defined as A in common namespace. I want to be able to make an alias B as buiseness logic struct to substitute that so called *implementation* just by using ```using```. But the question above remains the same.

Comment: Perhaps you should make `n1::n2::func` a template function instead? If the interface of `n1::B` and `n2::A` are equivalent enough then templates should work well.

Comment: n1::B and n2::A are considered to be the **same** target but in different namespaces to emphasis on logical field it they both used. You are not getting the problem right I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `using` directive is creating alias to `n2::A` with name `n1::B` that is already taken by structure declaration `struct B;` inside namespace `n1` (it is not another declaration of struct B, it is name aliasing). What you probably try to achieve is to provide a definition of your `n1::B` structure that might be done like this:

```
namespace n1
{
struct B {
    // definition here, you might use your struct A if you need
};
}
```

[namespace docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)

Comment: The goal is to use an already defined A, not to declare a new struct;

Comment: @ilev4ik, yes noticed that; The point is that you cannot create a synonym/alias to implementation with already declared name (struct B in your case); If you need to use your `struct A` logic inside `struct B` just do it by invoking A logic inside B explicitly; If your problem is more complex than that, please provide more details.

Comment: I got that. That's the case. The name `B` is reserved already.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot forward declared aliases.

a workaround, if appropriate, is to use inheritance instead of alias:

```
namespace n1 {
struct B;

namespace n3 {
    void func(B& b) {
        cout << "b\n";
    }
}

}

namespace n2 {
struct A{};
}

namespace n1 {
struct B : n2::A{};
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0679389a882e3cf)

but

```
n2::A a;
n1::n3::func(a); // Fail, a is not n1::B
```